# Destroy associated object from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting nil:NilClass errors, so I diagnosed the problem on rails c, see below:

```
irb(main):016:0> a = Product.find(216)
=> #<Product id: 216, ....>
irb(main):017:0> a.related_products
  RelatedProduct Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "related_products".* FROM "related_products" WHERE "related_products"."product_id" = 216
=> [#<RelatedProduct id: 162, product_id: 216, related_id: 248, created_at: "2013-08-20 15:37:03", updated_at: "2013-08-20 15:37:03">]
```

The problem here is related_id: 248 doesn't exist and confirmed it on the console:

Product.find(248)

I get:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 248]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Product with id=248
```

My question is:

1) How do I delete: `a.related_products` on rails console, I tried `a.related_products.destroy` and `destroy!`

Bonus: is there a way to delete all `Products` that has empty `related_products` from rails console with one command?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can use `a.related_products.destroy_all`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do something like

```
a.related_products.destroy_all
```

This will `destroy` **ALL** of the related products in the list.

```
Product.destroy_all(related_products: nil)
```

This will loop over all products and look to see if the `related_products` field is empty.

You may also want to setup dependent destroys. Something like

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :related_products, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete all products where related_products are empty check [destroy_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class)    `Product.destroy_all(related_products: nil)`

Also check the `dependent: :destroy` in your model.